# How to use js-cookie in a standalone *.js script?

Tags: javascript, gulp, es6-modules, js-cookie

I am using gulp to concatenate and minify a number of standalone *.js scripts used on my web site.  Basically this is just a catchall folder where I place little utility scripts that run on page load.  For example, one of them starts a carousel slider, another adds a class to the header that shrinks it on scroll, etc.  Each of these "features" has its own standalone *.js file.

Now, I would like to use the popular [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library in one of those scripts.  Unfortunately, since my project is not set up as an ES6 module, I am not able to able to import the js-cookie library the way it's specified in the docs, like this:

`import Cookies from 'js-cookie'`

When I do this, I get the error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

I tried changing it to this:

`window.Cookies = require('js-cookie')`

but that gave me this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Here is my gulpfile, followed by the feature.js script in which I'm trying to use the js-cookie library:

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Initialize modules
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

// File paths (note that src paths are arrays)
const files = {
  scssSrcPath: [
    'scss/*.scss',
    'scss/_pageContentModules/*.scss'
  ],
  jsSrcPath: [
    'js/*.js',
    'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js'
  ],
  scssDstPath: '../web/css',
  jsDstPath: '../web/js'
}

// Sass task: compiles SCSS files into style.css
function scssTask(){

  return merge(files.scssSrcPath.map(function (file) {
    return src(file)
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // initialize sourcemaps first
  .pipe(sass()) // compile SCSS to CSS
  .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ])) // PostCSS plugins
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(dest(files.scssDstPath));
}

// JS task: concatenates and uglifies JS files to script.js
function jsTask(){

  return merge(files.jsSrcPath.map(function (file) {
    return src(file)
  }))
  .pipe(concat('app.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(dest(files.jsDstPath));
}

// Watch task: watch SCSS and JS files for changes
// If any change, run scss and js tasks simultaneously
function watchTask(){
    watch(files.scssSrcPath, scssTask);
    watch(files.jsSrcPath, jsTask);
}

// Export the default Gulp task so it can be run
// Runs the scss and js tasks simultaneously
// then watch task
exports.default = series(
    parallel(scssTask, jsTask), 
    watchTask
);
```

**js/feature.js**

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const rs = cookies.get('referral_source');
if (typeof rs !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('referral_source = ' + rs);
}
```

How can I get this working?  Is there a way to do it using my simple Gulp setup, or do I need to go beyond and set up a full-on Webpack setup (with all the complexity that adds)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, Gulp does not support the ability to use ES6 modules. If you want to use them, you will need to use Webpack.

But `js-cookie` does have a jsDelivr CDN: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.1/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>`. By including this before your JS script, like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jscookie@3.0.1/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/feature.js"></script>
```